# Would habitable planets be possible in a dwarf galaxy?

Tags: evolution, astronomy

Does the fact that it's a dwarf galaxy affect the chances of life evolving?

I'm interested in how the closer proximity of other stars might affect the surface of the planet and it's ability to grow and sustain life. It seems like there would be more meteor strikes, more radiation in general, odd gravitational effects, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Tom. Normally single line questions are discouraged as they do not have sufficient detail available in them to provide clear scope. For instance, are you talking about increased stellar effects? The higher chance of super novas or black holes impacting planet development? Are you talking about simple life, or *intelligent* life? I recommend filling out this question some more so that it avoids closure as 'too broad'; this is a good question and i'd like to see it developed (and answered) properly.

Comment: I apologize, but even after your edit this is fundamentally unanswerable.  You're asking us to provide an authoritative conclusion about a type of galaxy we know little to nothing about.  Worse, even astronomers don't agree on exactly what a "dwarf galaxy" is.  And you're not bringing one iota of that debate to the question.  This question would need a massive infusion of information to be seriously considered for reopening.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing that we know of which would significantly change the frequency of planets in a dwarf galaxy compared with a larger one.  Planets are a common consequence of star formation and for a given level of metalicity (the fraction of elements heaver than helium) you should get roughly the same rate of planet formation no matter where you are.

One the planets form, we know of nothing that would impede the evolution of life on those planets.

There are two things worth thinking about.  We believe that low metalicity (compared with the Milky Way) would result in fewer planets being formed.  The metals (remember, to astronomers, oxygen and carbon count as metals!) were formed in stars, so the earliest stars had very low metalicities -- that's the main way we recognize them today.  The first generation of galaxies were made of low metalicity stars which probably formed comparatively few rocky planets.  So surviving dwarf galaxies from that era probably have few rocky planets and may thus have less life. (OTOH, they had plenty of time for life to evolve!)

Secondly, stars in dense clusters like globular clusters have many close passages with other stars, and their planetary systems probably get disrupted and many of the the planets dispersed into interstellar space, meaning frozen lumps which make Pluto look mild and no life.

But dwarf galaxies which aren't too old and aren't too dense should be teaming with planets and life.